# nextElementSibling returns "undefined". Why?

Tags: javascript, html

You can see my code below. The style of the text inside the span element is supposed to change after the user checks either one of the checkboxes, but it doesn't. I tried to print the span element to the console after getting it via nextElementSibling and the result was 'undefined'. Why?

```js
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
let j = 0,
  l = checkBoxes.length;
for (j; j < length; j++) {
  checkBoxes[j].addEventListener("change", () => {
    const spanElement = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(spanElement);
    if (this.checked) {
      spanElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
      spanElement.style.textDecoration = "";
    }
  });
};
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>To-Do List</h2>
<input id="input-task" type="text">
<button id="add-task-button">Add Task</button>
<ul id="task-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Send email to Bob </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Take vitamin D </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Practice coding problems </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Because "what is `this` in that change handler"? Did you mean `event.target.nextElementSibling`? You might be thinking of jQuery, which did some magic to make sure `this` inside event handing functions (regular functions, not arrow functions) referred to elements. That's not something normal JS does.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oops. Yeah. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `arrow` function which does not have it's own `lexical` scope, but instead takes on the one where it is defined. Replace it with `function` syntax and you're good to go!

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
let j = 0,
  l = checkBoxes.length;
for (j; j < l; j++) {
  checkBoxes[j].addEventListener("change", function(){
    const spanElement = this.nextElementSibling;
    console.log('here', spanElement);
    if (this.checked) {
      spanElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
      spanElement.style.textDecoration = "";
    }
  });
}
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>To-Do List</h2>
<input id="input-task" type="text">
<button id="add-task-button">Add Task</button>
<ul id="task-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Send email to Bob </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Take vitamin D </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="task"> Practice coding problems </span>
    <button class="delete-btn">Delete Task</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Except now the code still relies on scoping, instead of using the event target.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 2 different issues I'd say. Relying on `this` and using `this. nextElementSibling` implies that you want to target the next sibling onto which the event listener was bound. Using `event.target` would give you the element that triggered the event, and not where it was necessarily bound. (In case you want your event to delegate)

Comment: Fair, but there is no guarantee that `this` is the span in question either. The only way to _force_ that is through `checkBoxes.forEach(box => box.add...(...box.nextElementSibling...` (or the for/of equivalent - not much use for the old for loop with explicit var declaration these days)